why does kubernetes cronjob create another pod after successful?
We have set backoffLimit: 0 and restartPolicy: Never in our job. Yet, the job weirdly manages to create a new pod even after completing to run the first time successfully. Can someone please help me see what I am missing?
Here is the job spec
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-05-23T11:30:00Z"
  generation: 1
  name: pager-28607730
  namespace: monitoring
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: CronJob
    name: alertiplex-pager
    uid: ddfa060c-ed19-4216-b71e-fcab6c4d55ed
  resourceVersion: "2530322037"
  uid: 783d0f85-0251-4fef-afaa-842c0c0d5771
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  completionMode: NonIndexed
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      controller-uid: 783d0f85-0251-4fef-afaa-842c0c0d5771
  suspend: false
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        image: pager:v0.7.256
        name: pager
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsConfig:
        options:
        - name: ndots
          value: "2"
        - name: single-request-reopen
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Never
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  completionTime: "2024-05-23T14:50:17Z"
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: "2024-05-23T14:50:17Z"
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-05-23T14:50:17Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Complete
  startTime: "2024-05-23T11:30:00Z"
  succeeded: 1

When I try to do kubectl descirbe job pager-286007730 I get the below in the events. From here it is evident that the job has scheduled another pod
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  53m   job-controller  Created pod: pager-28607730-9hcbv
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  53m   job-controller  Deleted pod: pager-28607730-9hcbv
  Normal  Completed         53m   job-controller  Job completed
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  53m   job-controller  Created pod: 28607730-k8x5v

The corresponding spec of cronjob
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pager
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        metadata:
        spec:
          containers:
            image: pager:v0.7.256
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: pager
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 500m
                memory: 1500Mi
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 500Mi
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
          dnsConfig:
            options:
            - name: ndots
              value: "2"
            - name: single-request-reopen
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 30 11 * * 1-5
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 900
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
status:
  lastScheduleTime: "2024-05-23T11:30:00Z"
  lastSuccessfulTime: "2024-05-23T14:50:17Z"

